can i check how much resource used by vmms.exe process?
I use Windows Hyper-V 2016, and I'm aware that vmms.exe is responsible for managing VMs. However, I've noticed something unusual: during working hours (9 AM to 6 PM), vmms.exe uses minimal IOPS, but after 6 PM and throughout the night (until 4 AM), it uses significantly more IOPS. I'd like to investigate what exactly is happening with vmms.exe during the night. Is there a way to check the logs or gather more detailed information about vmms.exe?

I'd like to investigate what exactly is happening with vmms.exe during the night. Have you considered monitoring the usage from inside the VM guest? That is likely where the answer is.
